# Changing contact image programmatically is working for some devices and not for others

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am trying to update my contacts image by it's contact ID but when I test the code on a Samsung S3 it executes fine but no changes are made on the device. On my Nexus 4 it works perfectly, does anybody know whats going on. This is my code:

```
public void setContactImage(Bitmap img, String contactUriId, String rawID) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = scaleDownBitmap(img, 500, getApplicationContext());
        ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, image);

        ContentProviderOperation.Builder contentOp = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        contentOp.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contactUriId), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
        contentOp.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
        ops.add(contentOp.build());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: check catch part in s3 device.

Comment: There are no errors in my logcat for s3

Comment: If more information is needed, please let me know. I've been stuck on this all day!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off writing the photo to the raw contact display photo and marking it as primary and super primary.

[Add photo to a raw contact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.html)

Mark the data row as IS_PRIMARY and IS_SUPER_PRIMARY

[IS_SUPER_PRIMARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_SUPER_PRIMARY)

Check the PHOTO_ID under **Columns** for how the photo is selected for a contact

[Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)

Comment: Can you show me a code snippet of what you mean by "Check the PHOTO_ID under Columns"?

Comment: I meant for you to check the next link and scroll down to Columns and check the description for PHOTO_ID.